# MacOS Software as Midi Device

Tags: c++, macos, midi

I am writing C++ software in MacOS that can take input from MIDI devices and perform actions based on the input.  Another piece of software, QLab, can send MIDI messages to MIDI devices on the system. However, QLab cannot send midi devices to my software because QLab is not a midi device I can listen from and I my software is not registered as a MIDI device it can send to. Is there an easy way to have my device register as a MIDI device and then listen for commands appropriately?

Comment: Have you looked into [Core MIDI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coremidi/)?

Comment: @Caleb Yes! I understand how to listen for events from devices and play events but not how to BE a device that receive events.